# TChromium GetDevToolsUrl returns nothing

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, tchromium

I'm trying to call Chromium Dev Tools with this code from dcef3 demos:

```
procedure TMainForm.actDevToolExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  actDevTool.Checked := not actDevTool.Checked;
  debug.Visible := actDevTool.Checked;
  Splitter1.Visible := actDevTool.Checked;
  if actDevTool.Checked then
  begin
    if not FDevToolLoaded then
    begin
      debug.Load(crm.Browser.Host.GetDevToolsUrl(True));

      FDevToolLoaded := True;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

When i'm running programm, and pressing DevTools button, nothing happens, empty window, empty source code.
For Debug im trying this:

```
showmessage(crm.Browser.Host.GetDevToolsUrl(True));
```

And it return nothing(empty string).
But this code Works Fine in dcef3 guidemo... And not works in my Programm.

Whats a problem?

Here is dcef3 guiclient demo Full Code - http://dumpz.org/589068/

> Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching yields [a discussion on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/delphichromiumembedded/tMuywHt7qYM) where Henri Gourvest explains that for the dev-tools URL to work, you need to define a debugging port. For example:

```
CefRemoteDebuggingPort := 9000;
```

If that doesn't work, then you need to compare your code with the working demo and identify what else you're doing differently.

Comment: It does work... Just don't forget to specify that value before the `CefLoadLib` function is called; e.g. in the `initialization` section of the unit.

Comment: I hope so, @Tlama, but since we can't see all the code in the failing project, can't be certain that Priler hasn't already tried that, and that there's something else wrong with the code.

Comment: I could reproduce the problem (with plain vanilla project) and this resolves it...

Comment: I putting CefRemoteDebuggingPort := 9000;  in Form1.Activate procedure, but its still not working, where i should put this code ?

Comment: You need to assign the variable *before* you create any TChromium instances. Form activation is obviously too late. The demo you linked to assigns the variable in the unit initialization section, so you could try mimicking that.

Comment: Where is initialization section? I'm putting it on Form1.Create procedure, but still nothing... :(

Comment: You posted a link to the demo code. Look for the initialization section in that code. Or look for the initialization section in the code Henri Gourvest suggested.

Comment: Yeah, it works!!! I put your code in INITIALIZE section and moved some classes and it works!!! Thanks a lot for Helping :)

Comment: Anyway, you can specify value between 1024 and 65535; it's not fixed to 9000 (see [`this comment`](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/browse/src/ceflib.pas#345)).